# How to put custom HTML code in header of wordpress websites

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

This is my website and I need to put html code in order to make the header option form functional http://emmacombes.com/

But I have no clue where I can paste the HTML Code for header. Wordpress theme used - suffusion

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should find a file named `header.php` inside your theme's folder located in `/wp-content/themes/{your-theme}` that's the template file where you can add your code.

Comment: although it does work, don't use this cause your code will get lost when you update  the theme, use a plugin instead, like this one: `Insert Headers and Footers by WPBeginner`

Answer (score 3):

hello you can do it easily by going to wp-content/themes/your-theme/header.php

and paste code above the

or by login into wordpress

after login into wordpress go Appreance>>editor
in right side you find "Templates" below that you find list files search header.php there

and go to there and paste code above

Comment: for first task you need ftp of your server