# How to add code just after the <body> element?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have created a very simple plugin to add some custom code to an installed wordpress theme , It contains some info at the top then:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

echo '<style>.test{background:#000;color:#fff}</style>';
echo '<h1 class="test">Testing</h1>';
```

I want to add that code just after the `<body>` before any other element except the wordpress admin menu at the top if an admin is logged in So that the code isn't hidden beneath that menu.

So that every page on the website looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        //Some Code
    </head>
    <body>
        //WP Admin Menu If An Admin Is Logged In
        //My Custom Code Goes Here
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136498/how-to-put-custom-html-code-in-header-of-wordpress-websites

Comment: @codemirror , Thanks but these edits would be overridden when the theme is updated

Comment: @Frank exactly, that's why you create a child theme (https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) so it won't get overridden when the theme gets updated.

Comment: @HarisMustajbasic , I know how to create child-theme , But in this case some files would be excluded from the updates

Comment: This one is regarding creating plugin https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43672/how-to-add-code-to-header-php-in-a-child-theme

Comment: @codemirror , Thanks it worked but unfortunately I can't up vote your comment